# Not able to install angularfire2 via npm

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, npm, angularfire

I am trying to install angularfire2 from npm by running, but I keep getting this error

```
D:\angular\firebase\apartment>npm install angularfire2 firebase --save
apartment@0.0.0 D:\angular\firebase\apartment
+-- angularfire2@4.0.0-rc.1
`-- firebase@4.1.3

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN angularfire2@4.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@^4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angularfire2@4.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angularfire2@4.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angularfire2@4.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@^4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angularfire2@4.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@^4.0.0 but none was installed.
```

Comment: They are warnings, safely ignore .

Answer (score 1):

Last 5 of npm warn's are due to dependencies. You don't have the required modules to install angularfire.

Two possible solutions are, either downgrade your npm i.e. lower than 3.
npm < 3 can download the depending modules by itself or install the 5  depending modules first.